# Windows Batch file for checking ssh tunnel alive

Tags: windows, ssh, tunnel

Using putty (windows version), I have established a SSH tunnel for accessing MySQL. I can automatically start the session by putty -load "sessionname" -pw 1234
Using the windows task scheduler, I'd like to periodically execute a batch file which checks if the connection is still alive - and if not, the tunnel should be restarted automatically.
Any idea how to achieve that?
brgds, janosh.